# NIntegrate[] Gamma Function

Tags: special-functions

Gamma Function is known to be : [Source](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/02/0001/)

[image]

first i plot the function

```
z = 1;
f[t_] := (t^(z - 1))/Exp[-t];
gamma = Plot[Gamma[g], {g, 1.0, 5.0}]
```

[image]

then, i `NIntegrate[]` Gamma Function and `ListPlot[]` it

```
h[b_] := \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(b\)]\(f[
     t] \[DifferentialD]t\)\);
table = Table[h[b], {b, 1.0, 5.0, 0.05}]

lp = ListPlot[table];
Show[lp,gamma]
```

the graph should be satisfies each other but this is what i got. the `lp` graph is much bigger. 
[image]

Comment: Use Table[{b, h[b]}, {b, 1.0, 5.0, 0.05}]

Comment: Please post code in input form. See [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trying to compare the built in `Gamma` function with the integral definition of $\Gamma(z)$ then first define it properly

```
myGamma[z_] := 
Simplify[Integrate[(t^(z - 1))*Exp[-t], {t, 0, Infinity}], 
Assumptions -> Re[z] > 0];
```

Then we can check & see that they agree.

```
Clear[z];
Gamma[z] == myGamma[z]
(*True*)
```

If you want to see it graphically

```
data1 = Table[{z, myGamma[z]}, {z, 1, 5, 0.05}];
lp1 = ListPlot[data1, PlotStyle -> Red];
gamma = Plot[Gamma[g], {g, 1.0, 5.0}];
Show[{lp1, gamma},Frame -> True]
```

[image]